# Looping through multiple workbooks

Tags: loops

I am trying to write a script that will loop through 100+ workbooks which are all in the same directory. What I want to do is extract a sheet from each of these workbooks and copy them to one main workbook. The sheet I want to extract has the exact same name in all of the 100+ workbooks in the directory.

So far I have this, but being quite new to VBA I'm not sure if I'm going wrong somewhere:

```
Sub AllFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    folderPath = "C:\Resan\Bournemouth Parking\Survey Data\" 'change to suit

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.ped")
    Do While filename <> ""
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)


        'Call 'name of your other macro here
        'End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but having called `Dir()` once with a path, you need to then call it repeatedly without an argument so that it continues to loop within the same location.

```
filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.ped")
Do While filename <> ""
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
    filename = Dir()
Loop
```

You also only need to turn off `ScreenUpdating` once, but I would comment out this line while you are testing and fixing your code.